# Java: Passing two dimensional array in REST service

Tags: java, arrays, rest, spring-boot

I am writing a small Java REST program. I can pass one dimensional array but cannot pass two dimensional array as parameter. The code below is using Spring Boot.

server code:

```
@RequestMapping("/char2")
public String hello(char[][] c) {
    return "hello "+c[0][1];
}

@RequestMapping("/char")
public String helloInt(char[] c) {
    return "hello "+c[1];
}
```

client code:

```
// this works fine
MultiValueMap<String, char[]> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, char[]>();
map.add("c", new char[] {'b','c'});
String s = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/char", map, String.class);
System.out.println(s);

// this does not work
MultiValueMap<String, char[][]> map2 = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, char[][]>();
map2.add("c", new char[][] {{'a','b'},{'c','d'}});
String s2 = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/char2", map2, String.class);
System.out.println(s2);
```

client error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:97) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:730) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:688) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:644) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:399) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at hello.Application.lambda$0(Application.java:40) [classes/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:818) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
... 5 common frames omitted
```

server side error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [[C.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:208) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at
```

Comment: The error message is server or client-side?

Comment: client. I will add server error message.

Comment: Why do you send only `map` to both of the endpoints. Why not using `map2` for `http://localhost:8080/char2`.

Comment: modified. same error.

Comment: I don't know what's restTemplate so I can't make my own tests. However, remember that REST is about HTTP communication, not Java communication. There are a bunch of ways to interpret something as a one-dimensional array in HTTP, but nothing as a two-dimensional array. Attempts to do so will inevitably get weird and are likely to not be able to understand each other.

Comment: restTemplate is from Spring Boot.

Comment: Oh. Right. I'll make tests

Comment: Try `public String hello(@RequestBody char[][] c)`.

Comment: On the server side, there is a warning. Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8;boundary=kqQKbdMkoVtO0RD1lvgeTMQbY4wyWNNsiM7' not supported]. On the client side, it reports: Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 null

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a map instead of the array(s) contained in the map.  Try changing your rest calls as follows:

```
String s = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/char", map.get("c"), String.class);

String s2 = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/char2", map2.get("c"), String.class);
```

Comment: server side error:
 [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot convert a JSON String of length 2 into a char element of char array; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot convert a JSON String of length 2 into a char element of char array